# docker images access issue

Tags: docker, containers

Im not able to access my docker image. my setup is windows 7 and have the docker linux vm which is running on oracle vm. i have build my app and i can see my app using below

[image]

i dont know how i can access myapp container. since its wokring on localhost i believe i can access on localhost:port number. but i have no clue where i can see and how i can start. if you have face this same prob can you help ?

Update log hung :

in the below screen the server startup hung almost 10 mins and i terminate the process, any idea about this error ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown in your screenshot is the image list. So you would first have to `docker run` your image, binding the application's port exposed by the docker image (with `EXPOSE`, I'm assuming *8081* for the sake of my example) to the host:

```
docker run --publish 8081:8081 3b98
```

If you forgot to expose the port in your image you can do that on the commandline adding the argument `--expose 8081` to run.
Then, since your working with the Windows 7 setup, you cannot access your running application in its container on localhost but on the docker-machine's (the docker linux VM) IP. You can find out the assigned IP with

```
docker-machine ip
```

So if your application publishes itself on *8081* and docker-machine ip returns *192.168.99.100* you would find your app on *192.168.99.100:8081*

Comment: Hi i the docker run myapp is not starting . it hung in between.adding the log image in the post discription

Comment: From what I gather from your screenshot, the app is not hanging but finished starting up. It appears to hang because it does not produce any more log output. At that point you should be able to access the application with your browser.

Comment: I forgot (of course) an important detail, namely exposing and binding the application's port. See the edited answer.

Comment: Try running container in detached mode and with a pseudo-tyy, so: docker run -d -ti -p ....